# Docker run "error while creating mount source path '[...]': mkdir [...]: permission denied"

Tags: linux, docker, containers, permission-denied

I'm trying to mount a directory in Docker run:

```
docker run --restart always -t -v /home/dir1/dir2/dir3:/dirX --name [...]
```

But I get the error:

```
error while creating mount source path '/home/dir1/dir2/dir3': mkdir /home/dir1/dir2/dir3: permission denied.
```

All the directories exist for sure, and the strange thing is when trying to mount dir2 and not dir3 it is working ok:

```
docker run --restart always -t -v /home/dir1/dir2/:/dirX --name [...]   # THIS IS WORKING
```

All the directories ('dir2' and 'dir3') have the same permissions: `drwxr-x---`

Any suggestions on what might be the problem? why one is working and the other don't?
Thanks

Comment: You really have `/home/dir1/dir2/dir3`? Docker is trying to setup it for you means it think the folder not exist...

Comment: Yes all the directories in the path do exists, including the last one

Comment: Please include the output of `ls -al /home/dir1/dir2/dir3`, describe how the docker engine is installed and running, and describe the host (including whether selinux is enabled).

Comment: A similar error to this one which ends with the message "read-only file system" can be caused by installing docker as a snap.

Answer (score -1):

Check the permission for the folder you're trying to mount docker with `ls -la`, you might need to modify the permissons with chmod.

If you don't want to modify permissions, just add `sudo`to the beggining of the command.

`sudo docker run --restart always -t -v /home/dir1/dir2/dir3:/dirX --name [...]`

Comment: The permission is "drwxr-x---"(as I wrote in the question) which is enough to mount to dir2, but no success for dir1. Unfortunately, I'm working on a server where I can't change directories permissions, or use sudo (anyway the docker is with root permissions, but root permissions on the server are limited intentionally), or even create a new directory